is implementation allowed to reserve arbitrary names in global scope?
I've been porting a windows library to linux and it's failing on declaration of struct error_t. Both gcc and clang are giving an error message:

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/error_t.h:22:13: note:
'error_t'    22 | typedef int error_t;

I don't think the Standard reserves this name. Is there a way to tell the compiler not to expose the name in global namespace?

*_t names are reserved by the C standard library for stdint.h and by POSIX.

"allowed"? It's not like there is implementation police that will throw a compiler to jail. Implementations can do what they want.

@KamilCuk -- sometimes it helps filing bug report, no police required

The global namespace is the wild, wild west.  Best to tuck all your stuff into your own namespace.  For your protection.

@Eljay -- agree, except when it comes in 3d party library the options are limited. But I'd like to know the current situation. The names with _t are very common, and POSIX C library wants them for itself. So I wonder if they are familiar with this situation and do something to remedy this. Perhaps they did put them into posix namespace and I simply don't know how to enable it, perhaps there is a different runtime for C++ with everything in namespaces.

POSIX is a C API, and namespaces don't exist in C.

Your real problem is that the library you are porting is using a reserved identifier and gcc/clang are diagnosing that as an error (all identifiers that end with _t are reserved (since C99) for use in <stdint.h>) .     The solution is not to work out a way to tell the compiler to permit your code (library) to use that identifier.    It is to edit the library and change the identifier (and all usages of it) to something else that is NOT a reserved identifier - options include renaming it (say to YourLib_Error) or (possibly) placing it in a named namespace for use by your library.

Since libstdc++ implicitly enables _GNU_SOURCE, various definitions contained in POSIX and GNU extensions are enabled. Therefore, using another C++ standard library implementation (e.g. libc++) may improve the situation.

C++ standard defines two namespaces:  ::std:: and ::posix::.  The posix one isn't used for POSIX purposes (as of yet).  Alas.

@Eljay -- sad, POSIX had 26 years to fix this problem ☹️

That name is reserved by POSIX: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html.  In particular, it's a name ending in _t.  I don't think there's any way to avoid having that particular name exposed, and it's probably more trouble than it's worth.  Unless your library is massive, you're going to have an easier time changing the name of your library (and if it is massive, it's probably still easier to change your name).

That list of the names POSIX wants to be reserved is huge, and the names are rather common, probably clashes with every library out there. Shouldn't they put in a namespace, or perhaps there is a macro to put them in a namespace?

It's a C library, so namespaces aren't an option.  If you're in C++, the general advice is to keep your code namespaced.

just found out C++ standard reserves posix namespace, but not sure if it's actually used by implementation and whether the same mechanism with header names is used in POSIX as with c headers.
